# How to secure proxy without authentication?

Tags: proxy

I want to setup proxy on non standard port, e.g. 80.123.123.123:4863 and make it open. I need proxy without auth for my script.

Can it be secure? Can I use non standard port as alternative for login:password?

Comment: Your question needs more details of what you're trying to accomplish. What are the threats, platform being used, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it be secure? Can I use non standard port as alternative for
>   login:password?

No and no.

The best you could do is to configure the firewall to only accept connections from the IP address of the host that is running your script.